# Question with unsatisfying answers put on hold - should I delete?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, on-hold

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910675/elegant-way-to-disable-blocks-lines-of-c-code-from-compilation). I was hoping for a trick which would help me manage a code full of #ifdefs. I quickly got a comment warning me about the opinion-based character of my question. I also got two answers which did not lighten the matter (while being very informative), and an interesting answer which might be a bit on the off-topic side. My question was put on hold. No upvotes. Should I delete my question?

Comment: You can't delete it, it has several answers. Why would you want to delete it anyway if it has interesting answers?

Comment: The "interesting" one is off-topic. From the faq I learned that the question can not have upvotes and multiple answers, but I still see the delete option. So how many is "multiple"? I got unsatisfying answers and the community marked the question as opinion-based. I though this is a good reason to humbly delete my question.

Comment: You can only delete your question yourself if it has no answer at all, or exactly one answer with zero score. Anything more than exactly one answer is multiple answers.

Comment: I don't see it doing any harm in hanging around. Just let it be.

Comment: As an aside PIC / microcontroller optimisation can go fairly well on [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) where many understand you can be dealing with 1k of RAM/FLASH although that question is too vague and it would need to include more specific code.